# Remover dados duplicados e retornar o campo data de maior valor

Tags: php, mysql, sql, microsoft-access

Estamos migrando assinaturas de um banco de dados do Access para o Mysql, porém antes de migrar eu preciso tratar algumas partes dos dados. Eu necessito:

- Remover id's duplicadas
- Retornar o maior valor do campo data para estas id's

No próprio librecalc tem como remover as id's duplicadas, porém eu preciso comparar o campo data de ambos os registros duplicados, pois eu quero usar o maior. Então

exemplo:

```
id, data
2,  05/07/2016
2,  08/12/2018
```

Percebam que estão duplicados, mas eu preciso retornar a maior data entre estes 2 campos, que, no exemplo, seria `08/12/2018`. No final, ficaria apenas um registro com id 2 e com a maior data filtrada, `08/12/2018`.

Teria como fazer isto com SQL? Se não,

Teria como alguém me explicar a lógica para fazer isto em PHP? Eu tentei fazer um script no PHP que faz isto, mas não tem dado certo pra todos os casos.

Minha abordagem em PHP:

```
<?php

$file = file("access_old2.csv");
$new = fopen("access_formatado.csv", "w");

for ($i=0; $i < count($file); $i++) { 
print "---------------------";

$explode = explode("|", $file[$i]);
$explode[10] = strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", $explode[10])); // $explode[10] é o campo data
$explode_next = explode("|", $file[$i+1]);
$explode_next[10] = strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", $explode_next[10])); // $explode_next[10] é o campo data do próximo laço

if ($explode[0] == $explode_next[0]) { // $explode[0] é a id | não grava os dados repetidos e recupera a maior data de assinatura

    $date_atual = $explode[10];
    $date_next = $explode_next[10];

    if ($date_atual !== $date_next) {
        echo "diferente";

        print("<pre><br>"); //hack

        var_dump($date_next);
        var_dump($date_atual);
        var_dump(date("Y-m-d", max($date_atual, $date_next)));

        print("</pre><br>"); //hack

        $explode[10] = max($date_atual, $date_next);
        $explode_next[10] = max($date_atual, $date_next);
    }
    continue;
}

$explode[10] = date("Y-m-d", $explode[10]);
$explode_next[10] = date("Y-m-d", $explode_next[10]);

if ($explode[8] == "SP") { // coloca um zero a esquerda dos ceps de SP
    $explode[6] = str_pad($explode[6], 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

$explode[11] = "ASSCH";
$explode[6] = substr($explode[6], 0, 5)."-".substr($explode[6], 5, 8);

if ($explode[9] == "") {
    $explode[9] = "BR";
}

print("<pre><br>"); //hack
var_dump($explode);
print("</pre><br>"); //hack

fputcsv($new, $explode, "|", '"');


}


fclose($new);
```

Neste script, caso a id do loop atual `$explode[0]` seja igual a id do próximo loop, ele deveria retornar o `max($data_atual, $data_next)`. Funciona para alguns, mas para outros não. Tem haver com a ordem dos registros, mas já estou neste código faz um dia e não consegui progresso. (Acredito ser um erro na lógica do script).

TL;DR

- SQL para remover duplicados e deixar a maior data entre os duplicados
- Meu script não funciona para alguns casos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a coluna estiver definido como tipo data, é possível fazer isso diretamente no MySQL (deve funcionar no Access também):

```
SELECT id, MAX(some_date) 
FROM old_table
GROUP BY id;
```

Essa *query* vai agrupar a maior data por id. Em seguida você poderia mover para uma nova tabela, já com *primary key* definida:

```
INSERT INTO new_table
SELECT id, MAX(some_date) 
FROM old_table
GROUP BY id;
```

Veja funcionando no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54a790/1).

Answer (score 0):

Acho que isso pode ajudar:

```
$formato = 'd/m/Y'; // define o formato para dd/mm/yyyy
$data1 = DateTime::createFromFormat($formato, '05/07/2016'); // define data 1
$data2 = DateTime::createFromFormat($formato, '08/12/2018'); // define data 2

if($data1 > $data2){  // checa se data1 é maior que data2
    echo '$data1 é maior: ';
    echo date_format($data1, $formato) ;
}else{
    echo '$data2 é maior: ';
    echo date_format($data2, $formato) ;
}
```